# java concurrency with scheduledexecutor and infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to create two threads , one invoking a scheduler executor service and the other which runs in an infinite loop to fetch and process files.

I use the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            obj.checkFileExist();
            obj.enqueue();

         }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

And in an infinite loop I process files one by one:

```
public class processModel extends Thread{

    public static void getQueueSize(int size)
    {
        System.out.println("getting queue size");

    }
    public void dequeue()
    {

        // dequeue the queue
        System.out.println("dequeue");

    }

    public void processFile()
    {
        // process the file
        System.out.println("process file");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean flag = true;
        final int size = 9;
        final processModel obj = new processModel();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                while(flag)
                {
                obj.dequeue();
                obj.processFile();
                getQueueSize(size);

                }

            }

        };

        t1.start();

    }

}
```

How can I achieve both concurrently?

- Thread 1 - check if file exists in a folder. if yes enqueue it else sleep for a min.. - scheduler can perform this
- Thread 2 - if queue is non empty , process one by one. else sleep for a minute

How can I run these 2 threads concurrently. It would help me a lot if you show up some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using two threads doesn't make any sense.  The only time both thread will run at once is when the enqueuer is picking up files faster than the dequeuer can process them.  You solution would be simpler and more robust if you has a single repeating task which will ensure you never have one thread critically always ahead of the other ( and the code is much simpler)

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = new SingleScheduledThreadPool();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for(File file: obj.getCHangedFiles())
            obj.processFile(file);

     }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: which one i have to use ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1); or ScheduledExecutorService executor = new SingleScheduledThreadPool(); whats the difference

Comment: They do the same thing. I would use what you feel is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three threads running (in addition to the main thread): At least one from the `ExecutorService`, `processModel` and `t1`. But in principle, you only need one.

I think the job being scheduled with `scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` could just as well do the processing itself. After all, it won't take more than a minute to process the file, will it? This way, you greatly reduce the complexity of your program.

But if you insist on doing the checking and processing in different threads, I suggest you use one of the [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations from the JDK. The scheduled taks would [put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#put%28E%29) the file or whatever object in the queue and a second thread like `t1` in your code can then [take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) and process the object.

Comment: i am not sure why i came to the idea of 2 threads when i can implement in 1 thread itself. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other 2 answers. If you still what to use threads, the you should study the [wait-notify](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/wait_notify_how_to.shtml) mechanism. Because its much more efficient than running a thread every minute.
*In case its the first time you use threads and concurrency - You will not get it in 5 minutes! It will take some time till get it, so be patient.

**Edit:** As stated in the comment - its better to use existing libraries if possible.

Comment: I do not recommend doing *anything* with wait-notify if it can be done with `java.util.concurrent`. It's just too error-prone.

Comment: Any references for that? I have actually used 'wait-notify' just for homework at university. But it worked well.

Comment: "The built-in mechanisms for efficiently waiting for a condition to become true - wait and notify - [...] can be difficult to use correctly. To create operations that wait for a precondition to become true before proceeding, it is often easier to use existing library classes,such as blocking queues or semaphores, to provide
the desired state-dependent behavior." - Brian Goetz, Java Concurrency in Practice